# convert embedded ruby file to PDF file instead of only HTML file using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdfkit

I want to convert my embedded ruby file to PDF file after clicking on a link using Rails 3.I became able to convert simple html file to PDF file using `pdfkit gem`.I am explaining my code below.

> users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def download_pdf
       #html = render_to_string(:action => "/users/download_pdf.html.erb")
       #kit = PDFKit.new('http://google.com')
       #kit = PDFKit.new(html)
       #send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'report.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
       kit = PDFKit.new("<h1>Hello</h1><p>This is PDF!!!</p>", :page_size => "A4")
       send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'report.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
      #file = kit.to_file('my_file_name.pdf')
    end
end
```

In this controller page i did and got success to convert from HTML to PDF.

> users/index.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <%= link_to "Download pdf",download_pdf_path(:format => 'pdf') %>
</p>
```

When user will click on the above `"download_pdf"` link the `download.html.erb` will convert to PDF file and it should display as well as download in specified folder.The `download.html.erb` file is given below.

> users/download.html.erb:

```
<h1>Hello Rails</h1>
```

The above file should convert into PDF file with proper css .If i have css for this like below.

> application.css:

```
h1{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

How can i include this CSS in that PDF file.My other files are given below.

> pdfkit.rb:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
    #config.wkhtmltopdf =Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-i386').to_s
    config.wkhtmltopdf='C:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
    #config.default_options[:ignore_load_errors] = true
end
```

Please help me to resolve this issue and make this successfully.

By using `wicked_pdf gem` i am getting the following error.

> error:

RuntimeError in UsersController#download_pdf

```
Error: Failed to execute:
["C:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe", "file://C:/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf20150527-3204-calx6j.html", "C:/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20150527-3204-59mbli.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
Error: Failed loading page file://c/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf20150527-3204-calx6j.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
```

check the below code for this gem.

> users/users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def download_pdf
         render pdf: 'test',
           layout: '/layouts/test',
           template: '/users/test',
           handlers: [:erb],
           formats: [:pdf],
           :save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public', "test.pdf")

    end
end
```

> wicked_pdf.rb:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  #:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  #:layout => "pdf.html",
  :exe_path => 'C:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include your stylesheets by following:

```
def download_pdf
  kit = PDFKit.new(File.open(Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'users', 'download.html.erb')))
  kit.stylesheets << Rails.root.join("app","assets","application.css")
  send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'report.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
end
```

Comment: @ user123 : Ok one problem solved..But inside my app/views/users folder i have download.html.erb file present.How can i make it pdf file here instead of passing "<h1>Hello</h1><p>This is PDF!!!</p>".

Comment: it's possible with wicked_pdf

Comment: @ user123 : I am trying also this wicked_pdf gem but getting the error which is explained in my updated question.

Comment: you are getting a correct path for wkhtmltopdf then you can create using wicked_pdf

Comment: @ user123 : now you can check the error in my question section.

Comment: @ user123 : The wkhtmltopdf path is correct other wise it should not run when i am passing html tag inside this.When i am trying to convert .erb extension file it is throwing the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78910/discussion-between-rajat-474-and-user123).